# 改行の、\nと\r\nの違いは何ですか？

Tags: テキストファイル, 文字コード

改行の、\nと\r\nの違いは何ですか？
\nだけで動かない環境があり疑問に思いました。

Answer (score 21):

`\n`はLF文字(Line Feed)、`\r`はCR文字(Carriage Return)と呼ばれる制御文字です。

テキストの改行を表現する方法は、システムによって下記3パターンが存在します。その表現方法が使われている代表的なOSも併記しています。

- `\n`(LF)：Unix系OS全般、Mac OS X
- `\r\n`(CR+LF)：Windows系OS
- `\r`(CR)：古いMac OS（9以前）

コンピュータ上の表現としては`\n`1文字で扱うのが自然ですが、もともとタイプライター由来で`\r\n`が利用されていたという歴史的経緯があります。（CRが印字装置を左端に戻す動作＋LFが紙を1行分スクロールする動作）

Answer (score 2):

通信プロトコルではCRLF（\r\n）が使われる傾向があります。たとえば、HTTPやメールのプロトコルでは改行コードとしてCRLFが定められています。

- [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

Answer (score 1):

ＵＮＩＸ系のＯＳでは`\n`が使われ
Ｍｉｃｒｏｓｏｆｔ系のＯＳでは、`\r\n`が使われる。
`\r\n`でも通常は`\n`への変換が行われるために問題無いが
バイナリ扱いの場合とか
CygwinのようなＭｉｃｒｏｓｏｆｔ系ＯＳ上でＵＮＩＸ系の動作をさせようとする場合に問題になることがある。